# Game Center score submitted, but leaderboard shows no score

Tags: ios, center, leaderboard

I have a game that uses Game Center.

I'm playing the game, when the game ends, I send my score to GC. After that, I'm checking my score with the method below.

```
- (void)showLeaderboard
{   
    GKLeaderboardViewController *leaderboardController = [[GKLeaderboardViewController alloc] init];
    if (leaderboardController != NULL)
    {
        leaderboardController.category = self.currentLeaderBoard;
        leaderboardController.timeScope = GKLeaderboardTimeScopeAllTime;
        leaderboardController.leaderboardDelegate = self;

        UnityAppController* delegate = (UnityAppController*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

        [[delegate rootViewController] presentViewController:leaderboardController animated:YES completion:nil];

    }
}
```

That's just working fine, when I check it I can see my recent score on the leaderboard.

But the problem starts after. The next day, when I check it again with the `showLeaderboard()` method, the leaderboard says "no score". If I play the game and send my score again it's just working fine again, I can see my score! But, the next day the leaderboard says "no score" to me again! Like the leaderboard resets itself at 00.00 o'clock.. Just awkward..

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure that you do the correct code for submitting the score. This is a way that I really like. Even though you will get warnings because they don't want you to use it in iOS 7, it still works. Just let me know if it doesn't work.

`(IBAction)submitscoretogamecenter{`

```
GKLocalPlayer *localplayer = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];
[localplayer authenticateWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {

}];
//This is the same category id you set in your itunes connect GameCenter LeaderBoard
GKScore *myScoreValue = [[[GKScore alloc] initWithCategory:@"insertCategory"] autorelease];
myScoreValue.value = scoreInt;

[myScoreValue reportScoreWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error){

    //insert what happens after it's posted 

}];
[self checkAchievements];
```

`}`